# Facebook Share Button Creates Stories with link "via" my FB app URL - change to website URL

Tags: facebook, share

I don't have 10 reputation points yet, so can't embed image, sorry.  Please see the image that can help clarify, right away, what's wrong: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6BbO.png

I am having issues integrating Facebook buttons on my site. I have created a FB app to use with the integration - my like button (see http://soundsviral.com/2014/02/13/tennis-court-by-lorde-45/) is working just like I want it to. However, the share button next to it returns a story like you see above. The real disconcerting piece is that the link for the "Sounds Viral" name (which is the name of the app here, not the site) links to the app itself, which I don't want users to visit at all.) How can I change this URL to be my homepage (or the link in the post below, if that's preferable?)

I also which I could change "link" here to be "song", which is a supported og:type and is in use for my "like" button. However, for the "share" button, it just says "link". But that's less important to me than the actual URL in the story.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I am trying to solve the exact same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to set your facebook app to be a website app that directs facebook users to your website.

To do this:

1. go to you app page
2. go to **Settings**
3. click **Add Platform** button
4. Select **Website** option
5. Enter URL of your website and save